# Show 4 cctv in an Activity in Android

Tags: android

I am showing 4 CCTV live streaming (streaming using RTSP) in an activity. All CCTV are loading but it is taking too long to load and after some time, I am getting system not responding. So I want to know is there any efficient way to show all 4 CCTV in one activity (like can we make use of Async task). Please suggest some solutions so that app wont show application not responding message.

Comment: Set up the connections in background threads.

Comment: @RobCo can u please elaborate it??

Comment: Not really. There are many examples on multithreading in android, for example with an AsyncTask as you mentioned. I would also look into using an [Executor Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). However, in your question there is no code of what you have tried nor is there a specific question that is answerable. Please also see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23386/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-questions-on-stack-overflow-without-prior-research) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) thread about asking questions.